# Spring Java based config and JUnit does not work when webmvc is enabled

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, configuration, junit

I have started with a new **Spring 3.2.0.RELEASE** based application and I really wanted to do away with XML configuration since its a new project but I have run into a wall when it comes to writing **Junit** tests.

Here is The java config (**WebConfig.java**):
    package com.myapp.config;

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("com.myapp.controllers")
public class WebConfig{
     @Bean
     public InternalResourceViewResolver configureInternalResourceViewResolver() {
         InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
         resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
         resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
         return resolver;
     }
}
```

This is the **test class**:

```
package com.myapp.test.integration;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.springframework.test.context.web.WebAppConfiguration;

import com.myapp.config.WebConfig;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes={ WebConfig.class})
@WebAppConfiguration
public class HomeControllerTest {

    @Test
    public void testController(){
        System.out.println("Executing test");
    }   

}
```

When I try to **run** the test I get the following(I have enabled **debug** to get more info):

```
DEBUG: org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner - SpringJUnit4ClassRunner constructor called with [class com.myapp.test.integration.HomeControllerTest].
DEBUG: org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader - Delegating to AnnotationConfigWebContextLoader to process context configuration [ContextConfigurationAttributes@252d252d declaringClass = 'com.myapp.test.integration.HomeControllerTest', locations = '{}', classes = '{class com.myapp.config.WebConfig}', inheritLocations = true, initializers = '{}', inheritInitializers = true, contextLoaderClass = 'org.springframework.test.context.ContextLoader'].
DEBUG: org.springframework.test.context.ContextLoaderUtils - Could not find an 'annotation declaring class' for annotation type [org.springframework.test.context.ActiveProfiles] and class [com.myapp.test.integration.HomeControllerTest]
DEBUG: org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager - @TestExecutionListeners is not present for class [class com.myapp.test.integration.HomeControllerTest]: using defaults.
DEBUG: org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager - Could not instantiate default TestExecutionListener class [org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener]. Specify custom listener classes or make the default listener classes available.
DEBUG: org.springframework.test.annotation.ProfileValueUtils - Retrieved @ProfileValueSourceConfiguration [null] for test class [com.myapp.test.integration.HomeControllerTest]
DEBUG: org.springframework.test.annotation.ProfileValueUtils - Retrieved ProfileValueSource type [class org.springframework.test.annotation.SystemProfileValueSource] for class [com.myapp.test.integration.HomeControllerTest]
DEBUG: org.springframework.test.annotation.ProfileValueUtils - Retrieved @ProfileValueSourceConfiguration [null] for test class [com.myapp.test.integration.HomeControllerTest]
DEBUG: org.springframework.test.annotation.ProfileValueUtils - Retrieved ProfileValueSource type [class org.springframework.test.annotation.SystemProfileValueSource] for class [com.myapp.test.integration.HomeControllerTest]
DEBUG: org.springframework.test.annotation.ProfileValueUtils - Retrieved @ProfileValueSourceConfiguration [null] for test class [com.myapp.test.integration.HomeControllerTest]
DEBUG: org.springframework.test.annotation.ProfileValueUtils - Retrieved ProfileValueSource type [class org.springframework.test.annotation.SystemProfileValueSource] for class [com.myapp.test.integration.HomeControllerTest]
DEBUG: org.springframework.test.annotation.ProfileValueUtils - Retrieved @ProfileValueSourceConfiguration [null] for test class [com.myapp.test.integration.HomeControllerTest]
DEBUG: org.springframework.test.annotation.ProfileValueUtils - Retrieved ProfileValueSource type [class org.springframework.test.annotation.SystemProfileValueSource] for class [com.myapp.test.integration.HomeControllerTest]
DEBUG: org.springframework.test.annotation.ProfileValueUtils - Retrieved @ProfileValueSourceConfiguration [null] for test class [com.myapp.test.integration.HomeControllerTest]
DEBUG: org.springframework.test.annotation.ProfileValueUtils - Retrieved ProfileValueSource type [class org.springframework.test.annotation.SystemProfileValueSource] for class [com.myapp.test.integration.HomeControllerTest]
DEBUG: org.springframework.test.annotation.ProfileValueUtils - Retrieved @ProfileValueSourceConfiguration [null] for test class [com.myapp.test.integration.HomeControllerTest]
DEBUG: org.springframework.test.annotation.ProfileValueUtils - Retrieved ProfileValueSource type [class org.springframework.test.annotation.SystemProfileValueSource] for class [com.myapp.test.integration.HomeControllerTest]
DEBUG: org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader - Delegating to AnnotationConfigWebContextLoader to load context from [WebMergedContextConfiguration@a580a58 testClass = HomeControllerTest, locations = '{}', classes = '{class com.myapp.config.WebConfig}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', resourceBasePath = 'src/main/webapp', contextLoader = 'org.springframework.test.context.web.WebDelegatingSmartContextLoader'].
DEBUG: org.springframework.test.context.web.AbstractGenericWebContextLoader - Loading WebApplicationContext for merged context configuration [WebMergedContextConfiguration@a580a58 testClass = HomeControllerTest, locations = '{}', classes = '{class com.myapp.config.WebConfig}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', resourceBasePath = 'src/main/webapp', contextLoader = 'org.springframework.test.context.web.WebDelegatingSmartContextLoader'].
DEBUG: org.springframework.test.context.web.AnnotationConfigWebContextLoader - Registering annotated classes: {class com.myapp.config.WebConfig}
INFO : org.springframework.web.context.support.GenericWebApplicationContext - Refreshing org.springframework.web.context.support.GenericWebApplicationContext@5cf15cf1: startup date [Wed Jan 30 17:42:16 EST 2013]; root of context hierarchy
INFO : org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner - JSR-250 'javax.annotation.ManagedBean' found and supported for component scanning
INFO : org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner - JSR-330 'javax.inject.Named' annotation found and supported for component scanning
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor - JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
DEBUG: org.springframework.ui.context.support.UiApplicationContextUtils - Unable to locate ThemeSource with name 'themeSource': using default [org.springframework.ui.context.support.ResourceBundleThemeSource@7a487a48]
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@61266126: defining beans [org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,webConfig,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor,homeController,org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration,requestMappingHandlerMapping,mvcContentNegotiationManager,viewControllerHandlerMapping,beanNameHandlerMapping,resourceHandlerMapping,defaultServletHandlerMapping,requestMappingHandlerAdapter,mvcConversionService,mvcValidator,httpRequestHandlerAdapter,simpleControllerHandlerAdapter,handlerExceptionResolver,configureInternalResourceViewResolver]; root of factory hierarchy
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String com.myapp.controllers.HomeController.home(java.util.Locale,org.springframework.ui.Model)
DEBUG: org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate - Looking up JNDI object with name [java:comp/env/spring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain]
Jan 30, 2013 5:42:17 PM null null
SEVERE: javaAccessorNotSet
DEBUG: org.springframework.jndi.JndiLocatorDelegate - Converted JNDI name [java:comp/env/spring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain] not found - trying original name [spring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain]. javax.naming.ConfigurationException: Name space accessor for the java: name space has not been set. Possible cause is that the user is specifying a java: URL name in a JNDI Context method call but is not running in a J2EE client or server environment.
DEBUG: org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate - Looking up JNDI object with name [spring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain]
DEBUG: org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener - After test class: context [[TestContext@12a312a3 testClass = HomeControllerTest, testInstance = [null], testMethod = [null], testException = [null], mergedContextConfiguration = [WebMergedContextConfiguration@a580a58 testClass = HomeControllerTest, locations = '{}', classes = '{class com.myapp.config.WebConfig}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', resourceBasePath = 'src/main/webapp', contextLoader = 'org.springframework.test.context.web.WebDelegatingSmartContextLoader']]], dirtiesContext [false].
```

Comment: Are you using spring 3.2 for any specific reason? I think it should be better, if you are starting from scratch, to use spring boot: http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/ (spring 4)

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to set the active profile. Here's a running sample test.
Home Controller:

```
package com.myapp.test.integration;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Profile;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

/**
 *
 */
@Controller
@Profile("cloudx")
public class HomeController {
    @RequestMapping("/test")
    public String test() {
        return "test";
    }
}
```

WebConfig:

```
package com.myapp.test;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("com.myapp.test")
public class WebConfig {
    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver configureInternalResourceViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return resolver;
    }
}
```

HomeControllerTest:

```
package com.myapp.test;

import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.get;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.test.context.ActiveProfiles;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.springframework.test.context.web.WebAppConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MvcResult;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.MockMvcBuilders;
import org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = WebConfig.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ActiveProfiles("cloudx")
public class HomeControllerTest {
    @Autowired
    protected WebApplicationContext wac;
    protected MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Before
    public final void onSetup() throws Exception {
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(wac).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        MvcResult result = mockMvc.perform(get("/test")).andExpect(status().isOk()).andReturn();
        System.out.println(result.getResponse().getContentAsString());
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort but its still not working for me even after setting Profile. Same output as before except for the absence of one line this time - "DEBUG: org.springframework.test.context.ContextLoaderUtils - Could not find an 'annotation declaring class' for annotation type [org.springframework.test.context.ActiveProfiles] and class [com.myapp.test.integration.HomeControllerTest]"

Comment: I gave up ans switched to a minimal XML config and everything is working as expected. The XML xonfig is more or less equivalen of the java config with an internal viewresolver bean, a component-scan and and annotation-driven tag. The controller and test stay the same.

Comment: If you didn't change anything else in your project and merely switching from @Configuration classes to XML configuration files for loading your WebApplicationContext makes your test work, then that surely sounds like a bug. In which case, we (i.e., the core Spring team) would really appreciate it if you could create a repro project by following the instructions here: https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-framework-issues#readme -- Thanks! Sam

Comment: BTW, could you also provide any exception you encountered and the stack trace?

Comment: I did not get any exception. The output(debug enabled) has been provided in the original question. I will try to create a repo project soon. It just seemed that this might be a common use case and something that many others would have encountered if it was a Spring bug. So I strongly felt that there was something wrong that I was doing. But will open a repo project very soon anyway. If it ends up sucking the Spring Team's time unnecessarily, I apologize for that in advance.

Comment: Just wanted to add that the project was extremely simple. Nothing but a basic config as above, an almost empty controller, a minimal test as above and a java config as above.

Comment: An update: For some reason if I run 'mvn test', the tests run just fine(which works for me for now). They just don't run when I run them as JUnit test from eclipse.

Comment: Sorry I was busy these past days. @MickJ, Are you using an eclipse maven plugin like m2eclipse?

Comment: This might be m2eclipse issue because doing mvn test via commandline works fine. I am using IntelliJ and I can also execute the test successfully.

Comment: Late to the party, but my "Could not find an 'annotation declaring class' for annotation type [org.springframework.test.context.ActiveProfiles]" was due to the test file being in the wrong package. When I moved the test class into the right package, it ran fine.